# Use TLS client authentication with casablanca / cpprest in Linux

Tags: c++, authentication, ssl, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

I wanted to switch over to `cpprest` for `REST` requirements, however, in my scenario, `TLS` client authentication needs to be supported.

I went through the capabilities of the library, but I am not sure whether there is built in support for client authentication.

There are some hacks for trying to get this capability, but it seems only on `Windows` for the moment, which won't work for me, since my server is on `Linux`.

This page here, https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/810, describes one such get-around for Windows, and a hint of how it can work in `Linux` builds, but I am not sure how to go about it, since I have little experience in the area.

Work around for `TLS` client authentication on `Windows` -

```
#include <Wincrypt.h>

std::vector<uint8_t>  pkcs12_data; // "... your client certificate PKCS#12 with private key goes here ...";
utility::string_t     password = "pkcs12_password"; 

web::http::client::http_client_config cfg;
cfg.set_nativehandle_options([=] (web::http::client::native_handle h) {
    CRYPT_DATA_BLOB data;
    data.cbData           = pkcs12_data.size();
    data.pbData           = reinterpret_cast<BYTE *>(pkcs12_data.data());
    HCERTSTORE hCertStore = PFXImportCertStore(&data, password.c_str(), 0);

    PCCERT_CONTEXT hContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(
        hCertStore, X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_FIND_ANY,
        NULL, NULL);

    WinHttpSetOption(h, WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, 
                     (LPVOID)hContext, sizeof(CERT_CONTEXT));
});

web::http::client::http_client http_client(PS("https://secure.com"), cfg);
```